# Is my friend able to get out of question ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

A few months ago my friend signed up for Stack Overflow (not Meta) to ask a few questions on programming help. His questions were a little bit bad and consecutively I think 3 questions.

However, I tried to find his questions but they were all deleted. I asked him and he told me he deleted them.

According to this FAQ:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

He doesn't seem to be able to meet these conditions of post ban:

- He does not know how to answer questions for programming because he's a lot less skilled than I am
- How can he positively contribute when his questioning is locked?
- Deleted questions cannot be retrieved unless you have the link to undelete.

He called me earlier today about returning to this site and promises to study this site more often. However, he is not allowed to create new account.

But what else can he do to recover his rights?

NOTE: I have read that answer properly so correct my if I'm wrong but is there no solution for him to return to this site?

Is there a way to appeal a ban?

Comment: And why can't your friend come to meta to ask himself?

Comment: They can flag one of their posts (or if there aren't any then *any*post) as other and then ask the mod to undelete their self deleted questions so they can improve them

Comment: @psubsee2003 Is he allowed to?

Comment: @RichardTingle The system is automatic though. How do you know which mod gave the ban?

Comment: Question ban on stack overflow does not extend to meta

Comment: @puretppc he;'s not question banned on meta is he?

Comment: @RichardTingle Since neither of us knew that, I don't want him to dupe this question.

Comment: @puretppc no mod gave the ban, as you say it's automatic. Any mod can undelete posts however

Comment: @psubsee2003 He's never heard of this site. And this is only my first day on this site also.

Comment: @RichardTingle So a mod can find the posts even if it he doesn't have the link?

Comment: @puretppc mods can see every single one of your posts (deleted or not).

Comment: @puretpcc of course. They'd be pretty ineffectual mods if they couldn't. just get your friend to explain in an "other" flag. Note the mod cannot lift the ban, just undelete things so your friend can get themselves out

Comment: @psubsee2003 But there is no PM system so how does he contact? And I'm sory to say this but I've never seen a mod. Where can I find the list of mods?

Comment: @puretppc did you read Richard's first comment, he needs to flag one of his own posts.

Comment: Who the mods are is unimportant, you flag and and any mod responds. Is a reply necessary?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yeah but he didn't save the link of the deleted posts. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I can't find any deleted questions I have. And how do you contact a moderator?

Comment: @puretppc so he doesn't have any undeleted post?

Comment: Ahhh! You contact a mod by flagging. You don't need a link. They flag **any** question as other and explain within the flag

Comment: Your comment about just discovering this site today makes me wonder if you and your friend found http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans which has at least one link in it to meta...

Comment: @rene I think he means meta, which could explain some of his lack of familiarity with the basic functions of the site

Comment: @RichardTingle Yeah but the post is deleted so how is he able to access it if he has no link?

Comment: @psubsee2003 It's Stack Overflow not meta.

Comment: @puretppc does your friend have ANY undeleted posts?  He doesn't need to flag a specific one, any of his own posts will do.

Comment: @psubsee2003 He for sure means meta...

Comment: You flag **any** question and explain in an other link that they would like their self deleted questions undeleted

Comment: @puretppc I wasn't talking about the ban.

Comment: @psubsee2003 He blanked everything because he only had 3 questions deleted.

Comment: @puretppc do you have a link to your friend's profile?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Uh I actually don't. Does it work to search a person by name?

Comment: Does he have enough rep to comment?

Comment: if he has a common name, you'll need to sort through a lot of posts, but yes.

Comment: @rene I'm pretty sure you can comment with 1 rep only.

Comment: @puretppc only on meta, not on the main site.  But yes.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Uh how do I search? And he probably used some random username instead.

Comment: @puretppc then I think you need to stop this thread and ask your friend to come in and ask.  How can we help him if we don't know who he is?

Comment: @psubsee2003 All he has is just 1 rep. He never got any positives and he regrets his crappy questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate

Comment: Aha! There it is: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2785157/macro

Comment: Start out by having his profile page sanitized...

Comment: @rene Yikes did you see that rage he put in his profile? And yeah I'll try to ask himm.

Comment: The current profile summary is unlikely to help

Comment: This a question of him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880544/if-statement-examples-for-firefox-imacros

Comment: Seems a mod has just undeleted 3 questions

Comment: @RichardTingle Yeah I feel bad for him but if he can clean that up, would that be a possible unban?

Comment: I went and cleaned up the tirade in his profile, and undeleted his questions to give him a chance to edit them into shape. Not much more that we can do for him.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for cleaning that up. But any chance he can try and re edit them back in shape?

Comment: @RichardTingle Just by the look of those questions, he has 1 dupe Q. How could he edit that to make it good. I'm sure dupes are can't be editted to make good.

Comment: Those im looking for x can always be improved by showing what they've tried and why what they tried didn't work

Comment: Just a guess - it was the *deletion* of the questions that triggered the ban.  The questions aren't closed.

Comment: It is possible, deleted questions do count worse towards the ban

Comment: @MichaelT Uh he told me he got banned then deleted them. He duped like a question twice so I doubt he could edit to "undupe" them right?

Comment: Being a duplicate isn't a problem, being downvoted is

Comment: Admittedly being a duplicate doesn't help but I can promise you that question would have got downvotes even if it wssnt because it doesn't show any attempts at solving the problem themselves

Comment: @RichardTingle He didn't get any downvotes on that first question. And I don't think 1 question should change your status on this site. I was very sure it had something to do with overly duping.

Comment: Yes but the questions themsleves are very different, that was more important than actually being a duplicate or otherwise

Comment: @RichardTingle He asked a question for examples codes. Shouldn't those types of questions be deleted? I don't know what he tried in his codes but he probably couldn't make any new codes because of the trouble understanding. But the reason he wants to get back to this site is because he could ask different questions and more reasonable ones instead. Well I don't know what to say on how he could clean them though.

Comment: I have upvoted the best of the 3 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835745/if-statements-and-conditions-for-imacros-firefox) but I think that's the most I can do with them in their current form

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Judging by the comment replies you (and possibly your friend) have significant lack of understanding on how Stack Overflow works, and some of the basic features of the site.

That very well could have contributed to the question-ban if he didn't bother to understand what kinds of questions are on-topic and what kinds of questions are off-topic.  If your friend is to become unbanned, he is going to need to do some serious research into the site to understand its basic functions.  Stack Overflow is not some random forum where any question barely related to programming are welcome.

As for the ban, the only effective advice to contribute positively to the site.  You don't have to be an expert to answer questions, you just have to be willing to put in some work to find a question you can answer, or one that you can learn the answer too and then post it as an answer.

However, the most effective way to contribute positively is to fix the existing posts.  If the posts are deleted, then your friend needs to flag one of his existing posts with a custom message and ask a mod to undelete his existing questions.  Once undeleted, he can fix them so they no longer attract downvotes and start getting upvotes.  And if he doesn't have any undeleted posts, then asking a question on meta may be his best option.  A mod will see the question and either post a link or go and undelete them.  (Or a [wandering mod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208805/is-my-friend-able-to-get-out-of-question-ban#comment666788_208805) can see this post and undelete them for him)

## But

Before your friend does this, he needs to go back and learn what consistutes a good question.  If the questions are undeleted before he has an idea on how to fix them, then they are just going to get more downvotes and push him further into the ban.

Some reading material for your friend to help him learn how to ask good questions:

- http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/
- http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196815/why-is-my-question-off-topic-on-stack-overflow-even-though-its-programming-rel
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Assuming Brad undeleted every post, then he can't be that far over the line.  A few upvotes might be enough.

Comment: I don't really have that big of a misunderstanding when I write questions for Stack. Pretty much most of the questions I've asked were realistic on Overflow. Yes I'm learning how to program C#. But really, when he first joined he thought it was the same as a forum so that's how he ended up duping twice.

Comment: @puretppc you don't seem to have a problem asking question, but you seem to be very unfamiliar with the features of the site, that was all I was trying to say.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to learn. I know this may waste a little bit of time but I'll thank you well for this if I can find a way to get him to do well enough. The more I understand the likely chance of this.

Comment: @puretppc you may be interested in the [meta-tag:faq] tag here on Meta.  It is a fairly exhaustive list of how the site works.  the most important of which is [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) and should link to all of then others either directly or indirectly through another.

Comment: Sorry about the rage. It doesn't seem like he's able to do something positive since he only has one question and wouldn't deleting the duped questions make it even worse?

Comment: @puretppc Like I said, he can't be too far.  Someone can have 2 bad questions if the 3rd question is good.  He just needs to spend time fixing the one question and go from there.

Comment: Alright I'll try my best to help him out. Uh may I ask how long does it take for the system to know that the question is good enough and the ban should be lifted?

Comment: @puretppc should be instant as soon as he crosses the threshold.  Exactly what that threshold is is not known through.  "Good enough" will be partially based on votes

Comment: Why is your answer a community wiki while other's is not in this question? Sorry for necropost.

Comment: @puretppc because I specifically chose to make this answer community wiki.  I don't really remember why, but I generally don't like getting rep (as meaningless as meta rep is) on answers that I decide to answer after I've voted to close, so the fact that I voted to close is probably the reason.

Answer (score 5):

(The guesses about the mechanics of the question ban algorithm are just that - guesses stemming from seeing other people bump into it - don't take my guesses as fast)

I believe it was the *deletion* of the questions that triggered the ban.  Downvoted questions alone do not kick it, but rather closed questions (and deleted questions appear to be assumed to be closed).

The act of undeleting the questions *may* lift the ban.

Note however, that much of this activity appears to stem from a misunderstanding about what Stack Exchange is for.

This is a *community* driven site.  None of the stack exchange sites exist for the first purpose of helping you.  Its nice to think they do, but thats not what drives them and keeps the lights on.  Its about building a comprehensive set of questions and answers - *good* questions and *good* answers.

Asking poor questions deprives the community of answering other questions.  *Deleting* questions deprives the community of the seeds that keep it going.  And thus, the question ban - to keep people from asking things that take up the time or don't contribute (if you ask a question and then delete it - you're not contributing to the site).

Step back for a bit and look at some of the questions that have been asked recently that have a positive score ( https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a5%20is%3aquestion ).  Look at how those questions were asked and what information was included in them.

Also, before asking, ***search***.  Asking the same question as one that already exists on the site does not help the site substantially.  There is a lot of material out there that can help you - if you look for it.  Asking questions that are duplicates of existing ones in effects ask the community to again answer the question, or find the original one for you.

Comment: He deleted the question after he got banned. I don't know how long but assuming that the thing says "Oct 5 at 15:13" then that was after

Answer (score 1):

> - He does not know how to answer questions for programming because he's a lot 
>     less skilled than I am.

It's not a matter of comparison between the two of you, and it's  not a matter of skills more than it's a matter of effort done by the OP.
If he will make an effort to post a specific question, as long as he will follow some basic guidelines like searching for duplicates, showing effort (i.e posting your code or conclusions so far), etc., most chances that he will get a positive feedback.

> - How can he positively contribute when his questioning is locked?
> - Deleted questions cannot be retrieved unless you have the link to undelete.

He can ask for his questions to be undeleted. Afterwards he can improve the posts and potentially his reputation and ban status.